# what would be the correct type for "tools" in EnterpriseInput input?

Tags: api, types, graphql, schema, apollo

```
input EnterpriseInput {
    cnpj: String
    name: String
    email: String
    password: String
    tools: Tool
        
}

type Enterprise {
    id: ID!
    cnpj: String!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    tools: [Tool]
    
}

type Tool {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    brand: String!
    cod: String!
    qnt: Int!
}

type Query {
    enterprises: [Enterprise]
    enterprise( id: ID!): Enterprise
}

type Mutation {
    createEnterprise( input: EnterpriseInput!): Enterprise!
    # updateEnterprise( id: ID!, input: EnterpriseInput!): Enterprise!
    deleteEnterprise( id: ID!): Boolean,

}
```

Error message on console:

> C:\Users\Elias\code\web\backEnd-gestordeferramentas\node_modules\graphql\type\validate.js:69
> throw new Error(errors.map(function (error) {
> ^
> Error: The type of EnterpriseInput.tools must be Input Type but got: Tool.
> at assertValidSchema (C:\Users\Elias\code\web\backEnd-…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a mutation you cannot use standard Object type and must use Input type instead. And in input type you must use input type

So instead of

```
input EnterpriseInput {
cnpj: String
name: String
email: String
password: String
tools: Tool      
}
```

Try this

```
input ToolInput {
   id: ID!
   name: String!
   brand: String!
   cod: String!
   qnt: Int!
}

input EnterpriseInput {
  cnpj: String
  name: String
  email: String
  password: String
  tools: ToolInput    
}
```